# Alert on delete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add an alert while trying to delete a document.
I have created a remove action in the admin controller.
The issue I am facing is that I get an alert when I click the Delete Document button but on the alert message I have to click twice on the okay button to delete the document. Please help me find the issue.

parent_controller.rb

```
def remove_document
    @parent.document = nil
    @parent.title = nil
    @parent.save
    flash[:success] = "Document Deleted"
    redirect_to parent_path(@parent)
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Financial Document 1",  @parent.document.url %><br>
            <%= link_to 'Delete Financial Document 1', {action: :remove_document, id: @parent.id}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'} %>
```

application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.js
//= require filterrific/filterrific-jquery
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: probably you have 2 times included jquery, jquery-ujs or rails-ujs

Comment: @IgorKasyanchuk i have added application.js file. This is how I have it. Nothing is twice in it.

Comment: you need only 1 "ujs" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should try to remove, this you probably don't need that and `jquery_ujs`

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

or maybe try ther reverse and remove instead, but you may need this for bootstrap

```
//=jquery_ujs
```

Have a look at the [comments here](https://gorails.com/forum/do-i-need-rails-ujs-and-jquery_ujs)